# c# regular expression pattern

Tags: c#, regex

[code]>
                                    10                                /td>[/code]

I want to get 10 from this line.  But I need to preserve the pattern.  How can I write an expression that gets:

> , newline, ignorewhitespace OR included indeterminate spaces, 10, ignorewhitespace OR included all space, /td

Thanks,
JOe K.

Comment: What do you mean by "preserve the pattern"?

Comment: Are you trying to parse HTML? Then an HTML parser might be a better solution than a regular expression.

Comment: I am parsing html and using the HTML agility pack but it's not working for this particular case.

I need to get "10" from   <meta itemprop="image" content="http://www4.cdn.sherdog.com/image_vs/215249">
                                    10                                </td>
                                <td class="text_right col_fc_upcoming" itemprop="performer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
                                    <meta itemprop="image"

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2316200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll be nice and help you this time. =)

I assumed that the number you are looking for can change.

```
var result = Regex.Match(
      "[code]>   101   /td>[/code]",
      @"(?<=\>\s*)\d+(?=\s*/td\>)").Value;
```

But please, try doing it the next time... I'll point you a tool that could help in designing and learning Regex:

http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Comment: I did try with some tools.  But I appreciate your contribution.  Pierre-Luc Pinault also had a good suggestion in not using regex for HTML.  Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Yes, most of the time, you shouldn't be using regex with html... but sometimes, it is needed, maybe because you are in a hurry, or when what you need from the html is something so simple, that it is easier to use a regex. I have already worked with html crawlers that extracted information from it, and I can say for sure that: 80% of html parser for 20% of regex is a great ratio.

Comment: Also try [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) as a quick way to test Regex when designing them